# Why Packet drop is not captured under ifconfig?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I have provided below lines in order to simulate the packet drop on my Linux box.

```
# for randomly dropping 10% of incoming packets:
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP

# and for dropping 10% of outgoing packets:
iptables -A OUTPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

After that I run ping some_ip_address and when I terminate it ,can see line

```
100 packets transmitted, 84 received, 16% packet loss, time 99137ms
```

But when I run the ifconfig command I see packet drop filled is still zero

```
      RX packets:16007 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16207 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
```

Here, you  can see Dropped field in Rx and Tx packet row is still Zero.

Can any body let me know why packet loss didn't capture under ifconfig?

Answer (score 2):

This is because iptables and ifconfig statistics refer to different layers in the protocol stack. ifconfig statistics are for the NIC (Physical and MAC layers) while iptables rules execute once frames are received by the NIC and delivered to the kernel (INPUT) or before the packet is delivered to layer 2 in the protocol stack (for OUTPUT).

Comment: ok @rodolk,is there any way to simulate packet drop which would reflect in ifconfig?

Comment: I have to think more about your question but the first thing I could come up with is reducing the txqueuelen length with ifconfig. Maybe to 1 Byte? You could give it a try. For input, I have to think more, maybe slower the device driver action in some way, not sure.

Comment: Thanks @rodolk,I am able to understand the first part of your answer,where you say "iptables and ifconfig statistics refer to different layers in the protocol stack".Now my confusion  is if I simulate packet drop using ixia traffic generator, would it be captured by ifconfig stats?

Comment: I don't know ixia traffic generator. What kind of traffic does it generate?

Comment: Ok @rodolk ,will check and let you know about kind of traffic ixia generates.Also would it be ok to set ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 100 ??

Comment: I was reading around the Internet and found this http://sysadmin-notepad.blogspot.com/2013/06/dropped-rx-packets-in-ifconfig.html If you reduce the RX ring buffer and generate enough data to this device maybe you can simulate packet dropped. I tried 'sudo ethtool -G eth0 rx 48' (48 is the minimum I was able to configure)

Comment: I am looking packet drop at tx side,would ethtool -G eth0 tx 48 work ?

Comment: Sorry @rodolk but didn't get you "but if you're already seeing packet drop in tx " ?

Comment: You said you saw packets dropped at TX side?

Comment: No No @rodolk there is some confusion ,I didn't see packet drop at tx side and I am looking forward to see it if I run ethtool -G eth0 tx 48 and run ping command to send traffic.Would it work ,what you have to say on this?

Comment: I am out of luck here,when I run ethtool -g eth0 tx on my box ,it says operation not permitted:(

Comment: Probably you don't have permission. Are you logged as root? Or is your user sudoer? Would you contact me at rodolk@yahoo.com? So that this dialog is not that long. Then when we solve the problem we write it down here for helping others as well.